# Generating data array from POST data with a param-map

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following two things:

1. $_POST array with posted data
2. $params array with a path for each param in the desired data array.

   ```
   $_POST = array(
   'name'      => 'Marcus',
   'published' => 'Today',
   'url'       => 'http:://example.com',
   'layout'    => 'Some info...',
   );

   $params = array(
   'name'      => 'Invoice.name',
   'published' => 'Page.published',
   'url'       => 'Page.Data.url',
   'layout'    => 'Page.Data.layout',
   );
   ```

**I would like to generate the $data array like the example below. 
How can I do that?**
Notice how the "paths" from the $params array are used to build the keys for the data array, filling it with the data from the $_POST array.

```
$data = array(
    'User' => array(
        'name' => 'Marcus',
    ),
    'Page' => array(
        'published' => 'Today',
        'Data' => array(
            'url' => 'http:://example.com',
            'layout' => 'Some info...',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Doesn't $data=array(array['User']=$_POST['name']) etc. work?

Comment: In the specific example, yes, but I want do build the $data array programmatically based on the paths in $params. The above is just an example. The same concept shall be derived on various places.

Answer (score 0):

I would use referenced variables:

```
$post = array( // I renamed it
  'name'      => 'Marcus',
  'published' => 'Today',
  'url'       => 'http:://example.com',
  'layout'    => 'Some info...',
);

$params = array(
  'name'      => 'Invoice.name',
  'published' => 'Page.published',
  'url'       => 'Page.Data.url',
  'layout'    => 'Page.Data.layout',
  );

echo '<pre>'; // just for var_dump()
foreach($post as $key=>$var){ // take each $_POST variable
  $param=$params[$key]; // take the scheme fields
  $path=explode('.',$param); // take scheme fields as an array
  $temp=array(); // temporary array to manipulate
  $temp_original=&$temp; // we need this the same as we're going to "forget" temp
  foreach($path as $pathvar){ // take each scheme fields
    $temp=&$temp[$pathvar]; // go deeper
    }
  $temp=$var; // that was the last one, insert it
  var_dump($temp_original); // analize carefully the output
}
```

All you have to do now is to combine them all, they are not exactly what you want, but this will be easy.

And please note, that each `$temp_original` fields are pointing at `$post` variable data! (`&string` instead of `string`). You may want to clone it somehow.